# Error streaming from pub/sub into big query python

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am having trouble creating a dataflowRunner job that connects a pub/sub source to a big query sink, by plugging these two:

```
apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.PubSubSource
apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQuerySink
```

into lines 59 and 74 respectively in the beam/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/streaming_wordcount.py (https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/streaming_wordcount.py) example on github. After removing lines 61-70, and specifying the correct pub/sub and bigquery arguments, the script runs without errors without building the pipeline.

sidenote: the script mentions streaming pipeline support isnt available for use in Python. However, on the beam docs it mentions apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub.PubSubSource is only available for streaming
(1st sentence underneath the "apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub module" heading: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/2.0.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.html#module-apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't stream on Python Dataflow - for now.

Monitor this changelog to find out the day it does:

- https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/release-notes/release-notes-python

(soon!)

Comment: can't wait for when it does :)! it'll be an awesome feature

Comment: @FilipeHoffa, is it possible to batch process into big query in python?

Comment: @Evan, you certainly can batch process messages from Pub/Sub into BigQuery using Python; see example that Google makes available 
here - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes-bigquery-python/blob/master/pubsub/pubsub-pipe-image/pubsub-to-bigquery.py

Comment: Am I right in assuming that streaming still isn't supported with the python sdk?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa can't wait it coming

Comment: You can contact Google to add your project to their Whitelist. And then you can implement streaming with python